# domain name - the last '.' that connect anonymous root

Tags: dns, domain-name

The root node in domain hierarchy is anonymous, thus the last `.` is ignored in most case, right?

What happens if I access a website with the last `.`, e.g `stackoverflow.com.`, does the browser discard it directly, or the DNS will handle it, and makes some difference?

Answer (score 1):

The final dot is not ignored, it is defaulted to.

To start with, DNS query packets out on the network can only have the with-dot version. That's a protocol thing. So any difference between the with-dot and without-dot versions only exist on a local machine. In effect, it's a user interface issue.

Nearly all systems work so that when you give them a domain name, they look at it and then guess if it's supposed to be a whole name or if it's supposed to be a name in a local domain. The default rule is that if there's a dot in it, it's supposed to be a whole name, so it gets a terminating dot added if it doesn't already have one. It it has no dots, it gets the local domain name (with terminating dot) appended. This means that on most systems, `stackoverflow.com` and `stackoverflow.com.` will be treated as the same name.

It's usually possible to configure how many dots are needed before the name is considered to be a whole name. Normally, it's done with the `ndots` setting in `resolv.conf`. One or more suffixes that can be added to local names before they're sent out into the world are also (usually) configured in `resolv.conf`, with `domain` and/or `search`.